# R shiny : is there a special font for writing R code in verbatimTextOuput?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing a shinyapp which displays some R code in a `verbatimTextOutput` environment and I would like to know if there is a way to display this code as Rstudio displays it (with green font after hashtag for example).

I know that it is possible to change font with css (even if I don't know how to do it) but is there a "package" that automatically displays code as Rstudio does ?

Here's a reproducible example :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("base", placeholder = FALSE))
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$base <- renderPrint({
    cat("# I would like this to be written in green (or other color)",
        "library(this could be in blue)",
        sep = "\n")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: try the `shinyAce` package

Comment: thanks, but this package seems to allow people to write code as well, whereas I would like to show code only, but maybe I did not see every possibility of this package

Comment: there's an option `readonly`

Comment: ok, well thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having developed my app, I can say that Stephane Laurent's answer is the one that corresponds the most to what I wanted to do (i.e display reactive R code in a shiny app).

The shinyAce package is really useful, you can find some examples here (https://trestletech.github.io/shinyAce/).

Thanks anyway for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to hardcode html markup like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("base", placeholder = FALSE))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$base <- renderUI({
    HTML("<form class = 'well'>
            <p style = 'color: green;'>I would like this to be written in green (or other color)</p>
            <p style = 'color: blue;'>library(this could be in blue)</p>
          </form>")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Two problems : the first one is that the grey background behind the code does not display anymore ; the second one is that I have to manually change color each time, which can be very boring if the code displayed is long

Comment: Edited the answer. This would solve problem #1. As of problem #2, you would need to change color anyway. Give me your use case what do you mean by 'long code'.

Comment: I would like to eventually put hundreds of lines of code, and have the possiblity to print some reactive code (e.g if a box is ticked, then a part of code is printed). Stephane Laurent's answer seems to give me the possiblity to do that, maybe you have another idea (but your answer is useful anyway, thanks)

Answer (score 1):

You can not exactly do what you wanted to do, but there are two solutions of which I hope you will like one :-).

You can either use HTML Tags (use `paste0` to assign colors dynamically) or set the style with css for your `verbatimOutput`. Two colors is unfortunately not possible, since `VerbatimOutput` does not handle inline CSS.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                            #base2 {
                              color: blue;
                            }
                            "))),
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(selectizeInput("color", "Colors", choices = c("green", "blue", "red"), selected = "green", multiple = FALSE),
                  uiOutput("base", placeholder = FALSE),
                  tags$br(),
                  verbatimTextOutput("base2"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$base <- renderUI({
        HTML(paste0('<span style="color:', input$color, '">I would like this to be written in green</span> (or other color)<br>
          <span style="color:blue">library(this could be in blue)</span>'))
    })

    output$base2 <- renderPrint({
        cat("# I would like this to be written in green (or other color)",
            "library(this could be in blue)",
            sep = "\n")
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Ok, I will try with Stephane Laurent's answer and try yours if I can't achieve what I want, thanks a lot :-)